# Como puedo acomodar este diseño de tailwind en react native?

Tags: css, html5, reactjs, react-native, tailwind

Estoy queriendo logar que no sobre espacio y que cada caja cubra el espacio sobrante.
[image: Diseño]

Tomando de referencia la imagen, quiero que el cuadro azul se mueva hacia arriba (quitando el espacio sobrante) y que a partir de ahi se acomode el resto.

Básicamente como esta otra imagen :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esto, estoy usando Tailwind css , he aqui un ejemplo de mi codigo:

```
<ImageBackground source={fondo}  style={tailwind('items-center h-full w-full')}>

 <ScrollView style={tailwind('w-full ')} contentContainerStyle={tailwind('flex flex-wrap  content-center justify-center bg-red-800  flex-row w-full ')}>


 
 <TouchableOpacity style={tailwind('m-1 w-44 h-40 bg-red-500')}>

 </TouchableOpacity>

 <TouchableOpacity style={tailwind('m-1 w-44 h-64 bg-red-500')}>

</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={tailwind('m-1 w-44 h-64 bg-blue-500')}>

</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo a mano o crearte un modulo nativo con straggeredgrid de android y en ios tambien se puede manualmente, Si no hazlo en react nomas manualmente  y optimizalo. Puerba con recyclerlistview y como el overflowhidden no esta hidden en react-native puedes aprovechar eso para ponerle por afuera del padre y asi tener tu StaggeredGrid. Recyclerlistview te recycla las celdas para mejor optimizacion. Fijate si ya tienen soporte para una custom layout manager en recyclerlistview, en android y ios nativo hay.

Comment: https://github.com/muskeinsingh/recyclerlistview-gridlayoutprovider  Practicamente lo soportan aqui el ejemplo de crear su propio layout pruebalo